# Mongo: find items that don't have a certain field

Tags: mongodb, null, exists

How to search for documents in a collection that are missing a certain field in MongoDB?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible using [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/):

```
db.things.find( { a : { $exists : false } } ); // return if a is missing
```

When  is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the field, including documents where the field value is null. If  is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the field.

Comment: Be warned, `$exist` queries cannot use indexes (see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24exists).

Comment: @Theo: Starting from MongoDB 2.0 $exists is able to use indexes (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-393)

Comment: I was after this for Mongoid to use in a scope. Looks like this > ```scope :without_recommendation, :where => {:recommendation => {"$exists"=>false}}```

Answer (score 60):

If you don't care if the field is missing or `null` (or if it's never `null`) then you can use the slightly shorter *and* safer:

```
db.things.find( { a : null } ); // return if a is missing or null
```

It's safer because `$exists` will return `true` even if the field is null, which often is not the desired result and can lead to an NPE.

Comment: However, somebody reading the code might interpret it as the field has to be equal to `null` and not missing. This is actually unexpected behavior, because you wouldn't be able to do the same for `0` (which is also `false`), so `null` is kind of the exception here. Therefore, best practice is the more readable answer using `$exists: false` which is not ambiguous. Remember, your slightly shorter variant is not actually shorter if you need to have that comment behind it!

Comment: @Yeti if my goal is to find all objects that are missing a value for field `a`, either because `a` is `null` or because `a` is missing, then `$exists` is not good enough, as it won't catch the cases where `a` is `null`.

Comment: I think this is the best answer because `{ $exists: false }` does not use index if any, but `{ $eq: false }` will if there is one.

Answer (score 2):

just for the reference here, **for those of you using **mongoose**** (v6) and trying to use the `$exists` to find a field that is not defined in your mongoose schema, mongoose v6 will escape it.

see here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#strictquery-is-removed-and-replaced-by-strict

for example:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({ name: String });
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

// By default, this is equivalent to `User.find()` because Mongoose filters out `notInSchema`
await User.find({ notInSchema: 1 });

// Set `strictQuery: false` to opt in to filtering by properties that aren't in the schema
await User.find({ notInSchema: 1 }, null, { strictQuery: false });
// equivalent:
await User.find({ notInSchema: 1 }).setOptions({ strictQuery: false });
```