# MongoDB: Find a document by non-existence of a field?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to specify a condition of "where document doesn't contain field" ?

For example, I want to only find the first of these 2 because it doesn't have the "price" field.

```
{"fruit":"apple", "color":"red"}


{"fruit":"banana", "color":"yellow", "price":"2.00"}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo: find items that don't have a certain field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719408/mongo-find-items-that-dont-have-a-certain-field)

Comment: You can also try `db.mycollection.find({ "price" : null })`

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Try the `$exists` operator:

```
db.mycollection.find({ "price" : { "$exists" : false } })
```

and see [its documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists).

Comment: +1. However, keep in mind that such queries can't use indexing and might be very slow on large collections.

Comment: Great point -- thanks.  I know this caveat holds true in MongoDB version 1.8.x and before; but I thought queries with $exists field constraints can now make use of indexes in version 2.0 ...?