# MongoDB, how to retrieve elements which has not a matchable element into an Array?

Tags: mongodb

I have this kind of elements:

```
{  "_id" : 1,
  "docs" : [
    { "key": "blah", "count": 2},
    { "key": "wow", "count": 10}
  ]
},
{  "_id" : 2,
  "docs" : [
    { "key": "blah", "count": 11}
}
```

I want to retrive elements which has NOT the `docs.key == "wow"` defined. In this case the element `"_id": 2`.

Whith this query I get the opposite:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find(
  {
    "docs.key": "wow"
  }
);
```

I have tried combinations of `$exists` and `aggregate` but I don't find the proper solution.

Comment: Related but not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5719408/316700, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16221599/316700 because in my example I an looking for an complex element into an Array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do :

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find({
    "docs.key": {$ne: "wow"}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').find(
  {
    "docs.key": {$ne : "wow"}
  }
);
```

Comment: `Error: count failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "$not needs a regex or a document", "code" : 2 }`